# unable to understand new keyword in java

Tags: java

Probably a very noob question

I am new to java and am reading a third party api written in java...

I came across this declaration

```
Foo foo = new FooBar().new Foo();
```

I am unable to understand

```
 FooBar().new
```

Why is this declaration like this?

What advantages does one get in declaring something like above and what are the alternatives to such declaration.

Any advice/references would be greatly appreciated.

THanks

Comment: It's a [nested class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) thing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`FooBar` contains an inner class like this

```
class FooBar {

    class Foo {
      ...
    }
}
```

A new instance of the outer class is required to instantiate the inner class. Some classes don't make sense on their own so are implemented as nested classes. Here `Foo` has a relationship with `FooBar` and also has the benefit of having access to all of the latter's member variables.

Answer (score 4):

See @Reimeus' answer as to your first question.

As to your second question:

> what are the alternatives to such declaration

**Provided the inner class can be created independently of the outer class**, you can make the inner class static, as in:

```
public class FooBar
{
    // ...
    public static class Foo
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then you would instantiate with:

```
new Foobar.Foo()
```

A classical use of such a static inner class is a builder class for your class (recipe extracted from [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) -- do buy this book). This is a good way of creating immutable instances, as well as a good example of "fluent interfaces", since generally all builder methods return the builder instance itself:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static Builder newBuilder()
    {
        return new Builder();
    }

    private MyClass(final Builder builder)
    {
        // build according to data in builder
    }

    public static class Builder
    {
        private Builder()
        {
        }

        // methods to add data to builder, then:

        public MyClass build()
        {
            return new MyClass(this);
        }
    }
}
```

You will notice the static factory method `newBuilder()`; this allows you to write:

```
MyClass.newBuilder()
```

instead of

```
new MyClass.Builder()
```

to create a builder.